# Search Console can't redirect pages (htaccess issue?)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having an issue with Search Console.

Let's say the link: https://example.com/name

Browsers redirect to: https://example.com/name/

Inspector tool cannot do that, so it ends with a persistent "error redirection".

Then, if I decide to deindex the wrong URL, Search Console redirects to the canonincal one, so it deindexes the good one!!!

This is my .htaccess:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Remove www subdomain
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Remove index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>

# Remove multiple slashes from URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType font/otf otf
    AddType font/ttf ttf
    AddType font/woff woff
    AddType font/woff2 woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jp2                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf               "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript               "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                     "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                    "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</ifModule>

# Allow access from all domains for web fonts
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Header set Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

# Reduce MIME type security risks
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# Server-side technology information
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>

# Server software information
ServerSignature Off

# Disallow usage in an embed code. Items must be hyperlinked
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Frame-Options: DENY
</IfModule>

# XSS protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

# Set the referrer policy
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade "
</IfModule>

# This is for gzip, which compresses files
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Is there something wrong? Do I have too many redirects? Please check my config.

The same happens with http URLs, returning an "error redirection" when it should find the https version.

My site is build with Jekyll.

Comment: I checked that in my shared hosting, where there's the section: «Last 300 Error Log messages in reverse orde:», and it's empty.

Comment: I'm getting an error in Google Search Console > Coverage, called "Redirect error". Check this example: https://astrosigma.com/manchas-solares/ (try to open it without the last /, or with the http, or even adding www). All browsers redirect to this one, so it's ok. However, Google Search Console returns me that error. Is it a bug in the GSC? It seems, because I checked my redirections with multiple tools and all seem ok.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Browsers redirect to the URL ending with a slash. That's correct. However, Google Search Console, in Coverage section, it's not redirecting, so it throws errors.

Comment: In summary, if I inspect a URL without the ending slash, or with the http, or with the www, Google Search Console is not making the redirection, so it returns a persistent error in Coverage section.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of testing from `Google Search Console`.

Comment: Ok, np. BTW, could you edit or remove the comment containing the URL without the slash? I'm afraid Google will index it again and again, so it will be impossible to remove the error in my GSC.